# Python ftplib not logging in to FileZilla server

Tags: python, python-3.x, ftp, filezilla, ftplib

I'm trying to upload a file in Python to a FileZilla FTP server at ftp.scratso.com, however I keep getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "PythianRealms.py", line 2332, in <module>
  ftp = ftplib.FTP("ftp.scratso.com", "PythianRealms", "password")
File "C:\Python32\lib\ftplib.py", line 115, in __init__
  self.login(user, passwd, acct)
File "C:\Python32\lib\ftplib.py", line 400, in login
  resp = self.sendcmd('USER ' + user)
File "C:\Python32\lib\ftplib.py", line 255, in sendcmd
  return self.getresp()
File "C:\Python32\lib\ftplib.py", line 230, in getresp
  raise error_proto(resp)
ftplib.error_proto:  written by Tim Kosse (Tim.Kosse@gmx.de)
```

I've tried searching for solutions to this, but I haven't found this issue occur elsewhere.

The code is this (password changed):

```
ftp = ftplib.FTP("ftp.scratso.com", "PythianRealms", "password")
mapsock = urllib.request.urlopen("http://92.234.196.233/launcher-version.txt")
mapnum = str(mapsock.read()).split("'")[1]
mapsock.close()
f = open("tempmap.txt", "rb")
ftp.storbinary("STOR "+mapnum+".prm", f)
f.close()
ftp.quit()
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

**Edit:** In the server log, it shows:

```
(000185)13/09/2015 11:47:38 - (not logged in) (92.234.196.233)> 220 FileZilla Server version 0.9.41 beta written by Tim Kosse (Tim.Kosse@gmx.de) Please visit http://sourceforg
(000185)13/09/2015 11:47:38 - (not logged in) (92.234.196.233)> USER PythianRealms
(000185)13/09/2015 11:47:38 - (not logged in) (92.234.196.233)> 331 Password required for pythianrealms
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server sends back the following welcome message:

```
220 FileZilla Server version 0.9.41 beta\r
written by Tim Kosse (Tim.Kosse@gmx.de)\r
Please visit http://sourceforg\r\n
```

This is a very strange welcome message, since it is kind of multi-line but not proper multi-line. The lines are delimited by \r only instead of \r\n and it does not follow the standard used for a FTP multi-line response, i.e. that the first line should be "220-...." and the last line "220 ...".

While I can not see a clear definition of the characters allowed inside a single line of the response in [RFC 959](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc959.txt) text is commonly defined to not include control characters like \r apart from the line end. Thus it is no wonder that ftplib cannot properly deal with this strange response.

Comment: I've added the server log to the question, since the log shows it sending "220". Also, I found a config setting which allows me to change the "welcome message", but not sure what to do with it.

Comment: Also, I didn't write it, it's a [FileZilla](https://filezilla-project.org/) server.

Comment: @Scratso: you are right, but the response from the server is strange. I recommend you look at the configuration of the server, something must be wrong with it.

Comment: Okay, I deleted the welcome message, which sets it back to the default and the login works now. Apparently some things weren't on new lines that should have been... Thanks.

Comment: With the default configuration the FileZilla server separates the lines by `\r\n` and properly prefixes every line with `220`. The server must have been misconfigured. Probably if the `\r\n` in the configuration is replaced with `\r`, it makes the server not detect the new lines and sends whole message as a single line.